# How to send List from Servlet to JSP

Tags: list, jsp, servlets, request, response

I have `List<PostData>` with some posts for user in Servlet , how can i send this list to user's JSP page??  I need to split the server part and layout part.
Thanks.

This is my List:

```
public List<PostData> getPostforUser(String komy)
{
    ArrayList<PostData> posts = new ArrayList<PostData>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from posts where komy='"+komy+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            PostData postdata = new PostData();

            postdata.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            postdata.setOtkogo(rs.getString("otkogo"));
            postdata.setKomy(rs.getString("komy"));
            postdata.setText(rs.getString("text"));
            postdata.setDate(rs.getString("'date'"));
            posts.add(postdata);

        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return posts;
}
```

All is work, i made Connections and another things below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the list in your attribute and loop throught it on ur jsp.

```
request.setAttribute("posts", posts);
```

In your jsp:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="post">
   <tr>
     <td>${post.id}</td>
     ....
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Without jstl, would be something like this:

```
<%
  ArrayList<PostData> posts=(ArrayList<PostData>) request.getAttribute("posts"); 
  for (PostData post: posts) {   
%>
  <tr>
    <td><%=post.id%></td>
    ....
   </tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: without jstl in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Use request scope attribute, then you can access it with JSP EL via `${postforUser}`.

```
request.setAttribute("postforUser", getPostforUser("komy"));
```

Comment: It works if i have 1 post , but what if i dont know how many posts in database ? its may be 10.

Comment: Then use `komy like '%"+komy+"%'"`.